# Update database column on button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update database column on download button click. Seems easy yet when I click on button the counter in database isn't updated.

I'm not sure that this is optimal and correct way of doing this but here is what I have so far.

1. One input field where user pull the image from API
2. When image is loaded there is showed button Download and user can    download it

Also when user search for image I save in database what is searched for. So this is my controller function for pull the image + save in database the search string. This works perfectly

```
public function getImage(Request $request)
{
    $url = get_curl_content_tx('http://myapi.com/oem?url='.$request->input('url'));
    $items = json_decode($url, true);
    $thumb = $items['image'];

    $in_save = new Image();
    $in_save->url = $request->input('url');
    $in_save->save();   

    $LastInsertId = $in_save->id;

    return view('getImage',compact('thumb', 'LastInsertId'));
}
```

This is the function for update on download button click

```
public function getImageDownload(Request $request)
{       
    $downRecord = Image::find($request->id); 

    if(!is_null($downRecord) {
        $downRecord->update(['counter'=>'1']);
        $downRecord->save();
    }    
    return redirect()->route();  
}
```

The button in the view

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
    <a type="button" download="{{ $thumb }}" id="{{ $LastInsertId }}" href="{{ $thumb }}" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Download Image</a>       
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And routes

```
Route::get('getImage', 'ImageController@getImage');
Route::post('getImage', 'ImageController@getImage');
Route::get('getImageDownload', 'ImageController@getImageDownload');
```

When I click on `Download Image` button the image is downloaded but the `counter` isn't updated

Answer (score 0):

Upon discussing in chat I find out you are not calling the function getImageDownload in the view. So I modified the view code for him.

Comment: Thanks but why I got error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` on this line `$count = $downRecord->counter;`

Comment: do you have the counter attribute in your images table?

Comment: Yes, by default is `0`, `tinyint(4)`

Comment: Yes, like this.

Comment: have you replaced the function code exactly with the above coded function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151947/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-peter).